# How many elements of order 5 might be contained in a group of order 20?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Exercise from Artin's 2nd edition of Algebra.

How many elements of order $5$ might be contained in a group of order $20$?

My attempt:
 By the third Sylow Theorem, $|Syl_{5} (G)| = 1, 2, 4$ and it is also $\equiv 1 \mod 5$, so it is 1. Thus theree is a unique subgroup of order $5$, which contains four elements of order $4$.

Correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. There are four elements of order $5$.

Comment: Yes you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n_{5}$ denote the number of Sylow $5$-subgroups. By Sylow Theorems, $n_{5} \equiv 1 \mod 5$ and $n_{5}|4$ and both conditions imply that $n_{5} = 1$. Hence the number of non-identity elements of order $5$ is $n_{5}(5-1) = 4$.

Comment: Both conditions together imply that $n_5=1$. But not both conditions on their own ;-)

Answer (score 0):

assume you have two distinct subgroup H and K of order 5 ( otherwise the are the same). Now think about the set HK.