# After using Sylow Theorems, how can we say how many elements of order 5 might be there in a group of order 20?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, sylow-theory

I know this question is asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1551789/how-many-elements-of-order-5-might-be-contained-in-a-group-of-order-20).

I get the first half which says that from the Sylow Theorems (3rd one), we can say that a group of 20, must have a unique subgroup which has order 5. But from here what is the reasoning behind elements having order 5?

Comment: @AlejandroBergasaAlonso I linked it in my question. There's a specific concept I don't understand.

Comment: Since, $5|20$ , $G$ has an element of order $5$, say $a$.Then$H= <a>$ is a cyclic subgroup of$G$ of order $5.$ And $H$ contains all the element of order $5$.Because, if there is an element of order $5$ , say $b$ such that $b\in G-H$ , then $K=<b>$ gives a distinct subgroup of order $5$ , which is not possible. Now, order of every element of $H$ divide $|H|=5$.Hence there are exactly $4 $ elements of order $5$ in $G$.

Answer (score 2):

Each group of order $5$ is of the form $\mathbb Z/5 \mathbb Z$ because $5$ is prime. In the group $\mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z$ with $p$ prime you have $p-1$ generators, so there are $p-1$ elements of order $p$. That's because every non-identity generates the whole group since groups of prime order can't have proper non-trivial subgroups because such a subgroup's order would divide the group's order.

**Edit**: You don't even need to know that we are talking about $\mathbb Z/5 \mathbb Z$. Simply start with a group of prime order $p$ and follow the above argument to see that it has $p-1$ generators.

Comment: Why must $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ have p-1 generators?

Comment: @Anonymous I explained that in my answer.

Comment: @Anonymous . Any cyclic subgroup of order $n$ has $\phi(n)$ generators where $\phi$ is the euler's totient function which gives the output of number of positive integers less than $n$ and coprime to $n$. For a prime, $\phi(p)=p-1$. There are ways to calculate $\phi$ values . See wikipedia. It's going to be important for you further in group theory

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron It's true what you say but it doesn't answer OPs question. You simply say that it is as it is without explaining why it is so.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain I did not mean it as an answer. That is why I posted as a comment to your answer. As you only give the number of generators for prime ordered cyclic groups , I thought it might be helpful to the op if he also had the info as to how to calculate the number of generators of any cyclic group.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Okay, sure. That's usefull! Thx for the comment.